# Modifying rows in SAS based on Y/N column

Tags: loops, sas, conditional-statements

I am attempting to modify columns in SAS for certain rows that have a specific condition.

This is the information I currently have:

```
patientNum    siteNum   diseaseType   haveDiseaseD
001           12        A             N
002           14        B             N
003           15        C             Y
```

I'd like the new table to look like the following:

```
patientNum    siteNum   diseaseType   
001           12        A             
002           14        B             
003           15        D
```

So I just want to modify the table and switch the information in column "DiseaseType" if any patient has "Yes" under column "HaveDiseaseD".

Logic would be something like:

```
data have;
 set want;
   do i = 1 to dim(patientNum);
   if haveDiseaseD(i) == 'Y' then diseaseType(i) = D
      else diseaseType(i) = diseaseType(i)
run;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAS automatically loops through the data row by row. You do not need to specify arrays or dimensions. Since you only need to change one value of a column if another column meets a condition, your program will only be four lines of code.

```
data have;
    set want;
    if(haveDiseaseD = 'Y') then diseaseType = 'D';
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider maintaining the original diseaseType.  Someone is bound to ask about the prevalence or distribution of overridden disease categorizations.

```
data want;
  set have (rename=diseaseType=diseaseType_original);
  if haveDiseaseD = 'Y' 
    then diseaseType = 'D';
    else diseaseType = diseaseType_original;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

SAS uses = for comparison operator, not ==.  The SAS DATA step is an implicit loop, therefore you don't need to explicitly loop over patients.  In a simple step like this, the SET statement executes once in each iteration of the loop, and reads a record from the HAVE dataset.  That record is processed and then output.  There is an implied OUTPUT statement at the bottom of the DATA step.

Your pseudocode is very close to real SAS code:

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  if haveDiseaseD = 'Y' then diseaseType = 'D' ;
run ;
```

Comment: For operators I "always" use mnemonics.  EQ NE GT GE LE LT MIN MAX AND OR etc.